# Magento deployment process - DB Sync

Tags: magento2.3, database, deployment

I'm developing a Magento Store, I bought a custom theme and a lot of the theme content goes into the DB (eg. the content of the footer or menus). How should I proceed to deploy changes that I made locally to production?

I tried to run app:config:dump but such changes aren't saved into the config.php file.

The only thing that I can think of is to dump the entire database and upload to production. But this would overwrite my production DB. Which isn't good.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the way you have installed theme in local , install it in your production setup and run the magento commands but set site on maintenance mode first.

Comment: But I want to change things on my theme, how should I deploy this change?

Comment: Have to done customization in that theme ?